# Android trying to use a recycled bitmap, not in my code

Tags: android, bitmap

I get this stacktrace from the Market developer console every once in a while; I can't find any way to repro the error. It's happening while displaying a splashscreen ImageView as the app is first loading, but the stacktrace doesn't have any of my code. I don't even think my activity has even reached `onCreate`, though it's hard to tell without a log.

Indeed, I never actually use a Bitmap anywhere in my code; my only reference to the image is in my layout.xml.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

The only thing I do with this ImageView is set its visibility to `GONE` when I'm finished starting.

Is there anything I can do about this?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4721ec18
at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1044)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:323)
at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:923)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6761)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1663)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6517)
at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6305)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1588)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1661)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1409)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6764)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1663)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1661)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1661)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6764)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1663)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1661)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1390)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6764)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1887)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1432)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1764)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you using AdMob in your application?

Comment: I'm using MobClix, a competitor to AdMob. Why?

Comment: Because this issue gets talked about a lot if you are using AdMob, apparently it can happen occasionally due to some timing issues if you don't use a proper cleanup call.

Comment: I am having the same problem in my code, using another ads library widespace. Did someone have this problem and solve it in the meantime? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I jumped into the same situation and still got no clue. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 8):

This exception occurs when you try to recycle or use a recycled bitmap. You should not remove bitmap.recycle() function from your existing code, it may cause Out Of Memory Error. You can try this below code to fix the issue.

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) profileWallpaper.getDrawable());

                if (null != bitmapDrawable && !bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {

                    bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
                } else {

                    log("bitmap is already recycled");
                }

                bitmapDrawable = null;
```

*Note: profileWallpaper is your imageView object*

Comment: @Abilash shouldn't it be `!bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()` 'if NOT recycled'?

Comment: That could be a great workaround, but the actual solution is to know WHY a bitmap that should be used is recycled yet, otherwise you could not being showing needed bitmaps to the user.

Comment: It is not working for me, I used the same code. It is still showing same above error(Trying to use recycled Bitmap), Please suggest

Comment: I get this exception when I use WebView in my application. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

If you recycle your bitmap somewhere in your code, you should be sure that, when the app restart, your bitmap would be recreated. 
When you pass through the onCreate, no issues, but when the app is in pause and restarted it will not pass through the onCreate again, just through the onResume. 
I think you could recreate your bitmaps in the onResume method, but use a flag to create the bitmap in the onCreate or in the onResume, not both (onCreate and onResume are called together when the app starts and you could waste CPU cycles).

Comment: I added some clarifying remarks in my question. I never directly reference the bitmap; it's only loaded by the Android layout system. Do I need to recycle/recreate the bitmap myself by hand? If so, how?

Comment: It could not be related to your issue, but try to don't use the android:src="@drawable/splashscreen", it generates mem leakage. If in you, I should try to load/unload the image background programmatically. If you're not calling the recycle() explicitally, maybe the GONE parameters do it for you, I would not use it, just recycle() the bitmap.

Comment: @Zappescu Thank you very much! Your comment helped me to solve my problem. My app loads a lot of images from the internet and show a placeholder graphic until the images are loaded. The placeholder is set via android:src="@drawable/placeholder" and I accidentally recycled the placeholder, which produces an exception when the placeholder image is loaded again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use same image resources for different Activities while one of them is recycling its bitmap.

If you have this situation, changed the image resource of one of those Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to lower the ress of the image? It happened to me lots of times. If the problem continues after rezise the image, it means that the problem is in somewere else... I would look in the on create methode from your main activity or in the splashscreen code.

sorry my crappy english :)

C ya!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue with similar crash log. In my case it was just second ProgressBar inside the fragment. I had two lists inside it and ProgressBars for each of them. Removing the second one solved the problem. I can only guess that they were using the same bitmap resource for background or animation...

I've spent a lot of time to understand its reason, and it was just a standart ProgressBar! :/ 
Hope this help someone to save the time and peace of mind.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same `Exception` that is not coming from my application and found out that it is not related to AdMob.

The issue arises when you recycle a `BitmapDrawable` resource that was set through XML to your `ImageView`.

While resuming, android doesn't decode the image again whether it is recycled or not, therefore, you are getting `Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap`.

The way to get solve this issue is to reload the corresponding `BitmapDrawable` at `onPause` of your `Activity` so that android would not complain about the bitmap being recyced.

Here is how to do it:

```
Bitmap selectImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable);
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(selectImage);
```

**Edit:**
I realized simply setting `Drawable` of `yourImageView` to `null` also prevents this error. Just don't leave a `Drawable` that has a recycled `Bitmap`. Example code:

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```