# Bitmap recycle error with no bitmap recycle call

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an adapter that loads images into views. It runs fine except that when I test the ListView by scrolling really fast up and down the listview, I get a "Canvas trying to use a recycled bitmap". However I never call bitmap.recycle because I am using an imageloader. The error does not give me a location of where the error is happening. My guess is that the adapter automatically recycles bitmaps on its own since I do not make a manual call. This problem is not very consistent but I can recreate it if I really try. What is causing this problem or how can I locate it?

Here is the stacktrace.

```
11-26 11:01:41.131    1124-1124/com.android.wallfly E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.wallfly, PID: 1124
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@432bc210
        at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1084)
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:844)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:496)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1058)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15304)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14198)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14240)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14193)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14240)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15307)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14198)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14240)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15307)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14198)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14240)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15018)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
        at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2918)
        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3388)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15307)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:5184)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14198)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14240)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3272)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14135)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14240)
```

Here is the ImageLoader info

```
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
            .build();

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                .build();
```

Comment: I guess the "imageloader" in question is https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader ? If not, please reference it.

Comment: @shkschneider yes this is the imageloader.

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageLoader is doing some recycling obviously.

See [Android trying to use a recycled bitmap, not in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791742/android-trying-to-use-a-recycled-bitmap-not-in-my-code) and [Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129420/canvas-trying-to-use-a-recycled-bitmap-android-graphics-bitmap-in-android) for a better understanding of the problem.

How to fix it depends on your implementation (code) and your "imageloader".
Posting some code or the StackTrace might help.

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with my imageloader as you say. I have posted the config and options. I have suspicion of "reset view before loading". However I am not sure.

Comment: `resetViewBeforeLoading()` seems to cause some errors. Try to play around with options (including removing `resetViewBeforeLoading()`). See https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/362 sorry can't help more

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

> bitmap.recycle();

from your code. And it will solve your error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Explaining why removing `bitmap.recycle();` solves the problem could be helpfull. Thanks.